# Add link to image in the flexslider

Tags: php, jquery, flexslider

I'm using the [flexslider](http://flex.madebymufffin.com/) plugin and i wanted to know if there is an easy way (apart from changing the core of the plugin which is what i am going to do if i don't find an easy answer)
to go to link when i click on the current slide image. I set up the flexslider simply like this:

```
   $('#slide-top').flexslider({
           animation: 'slide'
           });
```

and in the view:

```
   <div id="slide-top" class="flexslider">
          <ul class="slides">
            <?php foreach ($gallery_top_slide as $image_slide): ?>
                    <li><img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/uploads/top_slide/<?=$image_slide['photo_url']?>" /></li>
                    <a href="<?=$image_slide['link_url']?>">Not need text on image</a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </ul>
    </div>
```

How can i do this?

For ex. if i click on current image go to www.google.com

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php foreach ($gallery_top_slide as $image_slide): ?>
                        <li>
                           <a href="<?=$image_slide['link_url']?>">
                              <img src="<?=base_url();?>assets/uploads/top_slide/<?=$image_slide['photo_url']?>" />
                           </a>
                        </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

An HTML-only solution:

Change this:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <img src="../myimage_1.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="../myimage_2.jpg">                       
    </li>
```

etc

Into this:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <a href="myurl_1"><img src="../myimage_1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="myurl_2"><img src="../myimage_2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </li>
```

etc.

Tested and worked. Be sure however to have the `pauseOnHover`-property of Flexslider set to `false`.